# How to dynamically replace token based on pattern

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm building an ETL that's newest ingestion client delivers a file a day with today's year month day build into the filename.  I'd like the process to replace the filename on the left with the filename on the right. For the resulting Filename I'm basing it off of today's date of 2023/02/23.  I'm not sure how to build the parameterized filename that includes offset and type.  For row 1 I'm thinking something like this: Data_{[yyyy-MM-dd][0][date]}.json but hoping someone has a better idea because it just feels wrong to me. The replacement type of date by itself would help, adding in replace and regex options would add additional flexibility. My question is how would I replace the parameterized file name with the resulting filename in a dynamic extendable way?

| Parameterized File Name | Resulting File Name | Offset | Type | Matching string | Replacement string |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Data_{yyyy-MM-dd}.json | Data_2023-02-23.json | 0 | date |  |  |
| Data_{yyyy-MM}.json | Data_2023-02.json | 0 | date |  |  |
| Data_{MMMM}.json | Data_February.json | 0 | date |  |  |
| Data_{MMMM}.json | Data_January.json | -24 | date |  |  |
| Data_{yyyy-MM-dd}.json | Data_2023-02-23.json | N/A | replace | _ | - |
| Data Data File Name Name.json | Data File Name.json | N/A | regex | ([a-zA-Z]+) \1 | $1 |

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: `DECLARE @Batch  VARCHAR(MAX) = '' SELECT @Batch = @Batch + CONCAT('SELECT ... WHERE', Col1, etcc) FROM Some and EXEC(@Batch)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what will give a jumpstart.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [FileName] NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tbl (FileName) VALUES
('Data_{yyyy-MM-dd}.json'), 
('Data_{yyyy-MM}.json'),            
('Data_{MMMM}.json'),           
('Data_{MMMM}.json'),           
('Data_{yyyy-MM-dd}.json'), 
('Data Data File Name Name.json');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @today DATETIME = GETDATE();

SELECT *
    , Result = LEFT([FileName], [start] - 1) + 
        FORMAT(@today, fmt) + 
        RIGHT([FileName], LEN([FileName]) - [end])
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('{', [FileName]), CHARINDEX('}', [FileName])) AS t1([start], [end])
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUBSTRING([FileName], [start] + 1, [end] - [start] - 1)) AS t2(fmt)
WHERE [FileName] LIKE '%[{}]%';
```

**Output**

| ID | FileName | start | end | fmt | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Data_{yyyy-MM-dd}.JSON | 6 | 17 | yyyy-MM-dd | Data_2023-02-23.JSON |
| 2 | Data_{yyyy-MM}.json | 6 | 14 | yyyy-MM | Data_2023-02.json |
| 3 | Data_{MMMM}.json | 6 | 11 | MMMM | Data_February.json |
| 4 | Data_{MMMM}.json | 6 | 11 | MMMM | Data_February.json |
| 5 | Data_{yyyy-MM-dd}.json | 6 | 17 | yyyy-MM-dd | Data_2023-02-23.json |

Comment: This doesn't cover everything that I wanted, but as you stated, it is a jumpstart, so I'm marking this as the answer.